How to remove default padding between Text() and SearchBar() in Jetpack Compose?
I'm creating a contact list app using Kotlin and Jetpack Compose.
I'm having an issue where there is a space between two composable components that doesn't show on the preview. The unexpected space is between a Text() composable and SearchBar() composable.
I have tried forcing the padding in both components to be 0.dp. I searched documentation and other online questions, but haven't found anything that helps.
Here is the code that I have and a link for the picture of both the preview and the app running (unexpected space highlighted in red):
import androidx.compose.foundation.Image
import androidx.compose.foundation.clickable
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.*
import androidx.compose.material.icons.Icons
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.AccountCircle
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Add
import androidx.compose.material.icons.filled.Search
import androidx.compose.material3.*
import androidx.compose.runtime.*
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.graphics.Color
import androidx.compose.ui.text.font.FontWeight
import androidx.compose.ui.text.style.TextAlign
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.sp
import androidx.compose.ui.tooling.preview.Preview

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
fun ContactsList() {
    Column(
        modifier = Modifier
            .fillMaxSize()
            .padding(horizontal = 12.dp, vertical = 36.dp)
    ) {
        // Top row with add button
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
            horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.End
        ) {
            IconButton(onClick = { /*TODO*/ }) {
                Icon(
                    imageVector = Icons.Default.Add,
                    contentDescription = "add contact button",
                    modifier = Modifier.size(32.dp)
                )
            }
        }

        // Header with Contacts title and SearchBar
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Contacts",
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
                fontSize = 36.sp,
                fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold
            )

            var searchQuery by remember { mutableStateOf("") }

            SearchBar(
                modifier = Modifier.padding(0.dp),
                query = searchQuery,
                onQueryChange = { searchQuery = it },
                onSearch = { /* Handle search action */ },
                active = false,
                onActiveChange = { },
                leadingIcon = { Icon(imageVector = Icons.Default.Search, contentDescription = null) },
                placeholder = { Text(text = "Search") },
                colors = SearchBarDefaults.colors(containerColor = Color(0xFFF1F1F1)),
            ){}
        }

        // Clickable contact row
        Row(
            modifier = Modifier
                .fillMaxWidth()
                .padding(top = 12.dp)
                .clickable { /* Handle row click */ },
            verticalAlignment = Alignment.CenterVertically
        ) {
            Image(
                imageVector = Icons.Default.AccountCircle,
                contentDescription = null,
                modifier = Modifier.size(80.dp)
            )

            Text(
                text = "You",
                fontSize = 28.sp,
                textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                modifier = Modifier.padding(start = 8.dp),
                fontWeight = FontWeight(400)
            )
        }
    }
}

@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun PreviewContactsList() {
    ContactsList()
}

Preview on the left and app running on the right:


I have just tested your layout, in emulator and in my device, i got no extra padding, try testing on another device/emulator.

Interesting... I wonder whats happening then. I will test it on another device. Thank you!

have you found solution for this issue ?

You have to override your windowInsets in your SearchBar
windowInsets = WindowInsets(top = 0.dp)

I believe the reason is that usually the search bar is at the top of most designs, so they added padding based on the specific device. That might also be the reason it looked fine on certain devices.
